# conditional forward fill within groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I have a data frame for patients and their visits to the clinic. Patients may take a drug at some visits, and only the initial dose is recorded, or when the dose is changed. If the dose doesn't change at the next visit, what's recorded is "drug ongoing? Yes. Dose changed? No". What I need to get is the exact dose for each visit.

I tried forward fill with groupby (groupby `patient_id`), but I'm stuck at how to insert the condition that only fill missing when drug is ongoing and dose is not changed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient_id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], \
              'visit_number':[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12], \
             'drug_ongoing':[np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], \
             'drug_dose_changed':[0, 0, 0, 0, np.nan,0, 0, 1, np.nan], \
             'dose':[40, np.nan, np.nan, 60, np.nan, 70, 80, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I tried:

```
df['dose_filled'] = df.groupby('patient_id')['dose'].ffill()
```

But in this way, all the missing is filled.

The desired new column `'dose_filled'` is `[40, 40, 40, 60, np.nan, 70, 80, np.nan, np.nan]`

Answer (score 4):

In your case , filter before `ffill`

```
s=df.loc[(df['drug_ongoing'].eq(1)&df['drug_dose_changed'].eq(0))|df.visit_number.eq(df.groupby('patient_id').visit_number.transform('first'))].groupby('patient_id').dose.ffill()
df.dose.fillna(s,inplace=True)
df
Out[38]: 
  patient_id  visit_number  drug_ongoing  drug_dose_changed  dose
0          a             1           NaN                0.0  40.0
1          a             2           1.0                0.0  40.0
2          a             3           1.0                0.0  40.0
3          b             2           NaN                0.0  60.0
4          b             3           0.0                NaN   NaN
5          b             4           1.0                0.0  70.0
6          c            10           1.0                0.0  80.0
7          c            11           1.0                1.0   NaN
8          c            12           0.0                NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hmm, did I miss the groupby then?

Comment: I see, same here, missed the groupby

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However in my case, the drug_ongoing column of the initial visit doesn't have to be 1. In that case, your answer doesn't carry forward the initial dose. I think I made a bad example. I have just edited the question.

Comment: @WeNYoBen The initial dose could occur at any visit. Some patients start taking the drug very late. I edited the question again. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
np.where(~df.drug_dose_changed.astype(bool),df.dose.ffill(),df.dose)
```

Output:

```
array([40., 40., 40., 60., nan, 70., 80., nan, nan])
```